Can't think of this movie which has aliens and a planetary colony in it
I am trying to remember the title of a certain movie which I THINK was made before the 2000's, probably the 90's. Though I am not entirely sure.
I can vaguely remember parts of the movie, which I will point out below - 

The plot is based in a planetary colony created by humans, where workers with their families colonized.
The colony was built on the side of a cliff. My memory is a little fuzzy, but I think the cliffs surrounded the colony much like a cove. 
I vaguely remember the atmosphere of the planet being brown and dusty.
After a certain incident (by an unknown entity, possibly an alien?) the colonists are killed one by one. I think there were survivors left though.
This I am not 100% certain I think I also remember some characters shooting outside from the colony. I cannot be sure if this was before or after the incident (or even if this occurred at all).

Then a group of soldiers arrive on the planet to investigate what happened only to find the colony ravaged.
This may seem very similar to the Aliens movies, but it isn't. 
If anyone has any clues or possible titles, please let me know. Any possible title is fine.

Sounds like something out of the Starship Troopers franchise. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/

I was about to say Alien 2, and then I read your caveat.

Unfortunately the ST series isn't what I'm looking for either :/

Could it be the movie "Screamers" from 1995? When I heard your description it's the first thing that came to mind.
This is from Wikipedia:

The year is 2078. The planet Sirius 6B, once a thriving mining hub, has been reduced to a toxic wasteland by a civil war between the Alliance, a resistance group composed of the colony's former mining and science personnel, and their employers, the New Economic Block (NEB). Five years into the war, Alliance scientists created and deployed Autonomous Mobile Swords (AMS) — artificially intelligent self-replicating machines that hunt down and kill NEB soldiers on their own. They are nicknamed "screamers" because of the high-pitched noise they emit as they attack. Screamers cannot distinguish friend from foe; they track targets by their heartbeats, so Alliance soldiers wear "tabs" which broadcast a signal canceling out the wearer's heartbeat and rendering them "invisible" to the machines.
Both armies are exhausted, poorly supplied, and undermanned. Consequently, a fragile stalemate is in effect. A message guaranteeing safe passage through NEB territory to discuss a peace treaty is recovered from a dead NEB soldier, killed by screamers as he approached the Alliance compound. As the Alliance's commanding officer, Joe Hendricksson (Weller), ponders this development, he receives word from Alliance Command on Earth that peace negotiations are underway with the NEB; but private Michael "Ace" Jefferson (Andrew Lauer), who has just crash-landed on a troop ship from Earth, tells Hendricksson that this is not true. Hendricksson is not surprised, as he has come to believe that neither side has any intention of negotiating. Commercial expediency, he reasons, will motivate both the company and the resistance group to simply abandon their armies on the ruined planet, as each pursues new ventures on other planets.


Thanks for your reply! I don't think it's the one I'm looking for, though I think I once watched this before (think I'll check it out again!).

I think you're looking for Ghosts of Mars (2001).

Colonised and terraformed Mars, workers and families, society is matriarchal, with women in most positions of authority. 
The colony isn't near a cliff, BUT it is in a man-made ravine or valley, and the sides of the valley rise above the buildings and look sort of cliff-like.

The whole film is very brown and dusty.  In fact, too brown and dusty to tell what's going on in some scenes.
A team of heavily-armed police (who you could easily remember as soldiers) lead by a woman (Natasha Henstridge) with Jason Statham and Ice Cube are sent to a remote mining town.

They find many colonists dead and missing, some killed by an unkown force (I'm trying to avoid spoilers here).
More colonists (and some of the cops) are killed one by one. 
As I was writing this it also occurred to me that it could be Soldier with Kurt Russell (1998).  Although that's less likely. If it's not GoM, then I'll tell you about Soldier.
Caveat; Ghosts of Mars is NOT a very good film.
Blurry, spoiler-filled trailer; 



I am not entirely sure about this one, but I will check it out and see if it is or not. Will let you know :)
